# On UnsatisfiedLinkError, clarification needed

Tags: intellij-idea

When building the project from command line using `mvn clean install` everything builds without any issues.

When running some tests that use precompiled C libraries from `IntelliJ`, tests fail with `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

I may be completely off here, but does `IntelliJ` not see the `.so` file? Is so, how can it be added please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared library fails to load with `UnsatisfiedLinkError` if:

1. it's not in the working directory configured in the test run configuration.
2. it's not in `PATH` environment (on Mac Terminal and GUI apps have different environment, see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891)). Run IDEA from the Terminal `open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/` to make environment the same.
3. it's not in the location specified using `-Djava.library.path` VM option.
4. `.so` depends on some other library that is not found for any of the 1-3 reasons (or the dependency of that dependency is not found, etc).